# Why does my pure CSS parallax scrolling stop working on completion of page loading in Drupal 9

Tags: css, drupal, parallax

I am completing a migration of a Drupal 7 website to Drupal 9 (which will immediately move to Drupal 10). The pure CSS parallax scrolling that I implemented in Drupal 7 works during page loading in Drupal 9, but as soon as the page has completed loading, the parallax scrolling stops working.

I have examined each of the elements of the CSS and explored other possible values.

I referred to the pure CSS tutorial here: https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ which approaches the effect differently, so I would like to avoid re-writing all the HTML if possible.

I made a JSFiddle entry with my HTML and CSS to show that it works outside of the Drupal environment.

Comment: Were you planning on adding a link to your code?

Comment: This is the link to the JSFiddle showing that I'm getting the results I want outside of the Drupal 9 framework: https://jsfiddle.net/seumasgagne/5omgs7Lv/10/  The site in question is a Federal government one, so the development environment isn't reachable other than on the trusted campus network.

Comment: I see no paralax effect in the jsfiddle, I just see a fixed background image, and looking at the css, it's working how I would expect it to.